# Getting error while writting code for onClickListener() in android

Tags: android

Ma COde:-

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener()// error Line
    {
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
        startActivity(new Intent("com.example.crazy.HistoryActivity"));
        }});
}
```

Error Getting:-
Multiple markers at this line
    - onClickListener cannot be resolved to a type
    - The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new 
     onClickListener(){})

Comment: have you `import android.view.View.OnClickListener;` ? ...... if you are using eclipse press `CTRL + SHIFT + O`

Comment: i tried dat also but still same error

Comment: have u tried @ToonSuperLove answer ?

Answer (score 2):

use OnClickListener() not onClickListener()

Answer (score 0):

You need to `import View.OnClickListener;`

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

capitalized letter `OnClickListener` it's a class name

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()// error Line
    {
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
        startActivity(new Intent("com.example.crazy.HistoryActivity"));
        }});
```

clean your project after that

Comment: @Dhr you are welcome don't forget to mark the anwer as accepted, You are a new member see this post to learn how to accept an answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

**1.** In **Java** we follow the **Camel case for naming the variables, methods, class, interface etc.**

**2.** But `OnClickListener()` is an **Interface Not a method**, So according to the Java naming convention its **Uppercase "O", not LowerCase "o"**.

**3** Try this...

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()// error Line
    {
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
        startActivity(new Intent("com.example.crazy.HistoryActivity"));
        }});
```